# No Sound via Displayport [elementary OS 7 ; AMD GPU]

Tags: updates, sound, amd, horus, eos7

I got the issue, that I don't get sound via Displayport working for me.
First of all the sounds work but not via Displayport.
So eg. with headphones it's working.

Also there is noch Sound for DP or HDMI in settings.
Neither it is with pavucontrol.

some help/ideas?

Comment: This is almost always due to the video driver. Have you confirmed that the most recent version is installed for your card? 